# Is there a way to add spaces into a score without using rests?

Tags: lilypond

Something that looks like this:

[image]

In case you're wondering, I'm trying to type up melodic dictations for a mock AP Music Theory exam.

Edit: didn't include this originally, but I couldn't find anything about this just searching or looking at LilyPond's documentation, so I came here

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I found is to use \hideNotes, then just use filler; for instance,

```
\stemOff bes,4 \hideNotes bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 bes,8 \bar "|."
```

yields

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Invisible spacer rests can be inserted with an `s` followed by a note value number:

```lilypond
{
  \clef "bass"
    \once\omit Stem des4 s4 s2 |
    \repeat unfold 3 { s1 } |
    \bar "|." 
}
```

See: [1.2.2 Writing rests - Invisible rests](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/writing-rests#invisible-rests)